# Header and footer passed in stdin

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, wkhtmltopdf

Is there a way to use WkHtmlToPdf and pass header/footer directly as html code as parameter and not via external file?

I am using WkHtmlToPdf in my MVC .NET app, wrapped with this solution: http://www.megustaulises.com/2012/12/mvcnet-convert-html-to-pdf-with-pechkin.html

I have some dynamic data I need to pass to header and footer and I don't wont to save it to file system as a html file only for passing it to WkHtmlToPdf.

Is there any other soluton?

Comment: I'm struggling with this situation too. What I do as a workaround is use a template, repalce dynamic values, write to tempfile, fire wkhtmltopdf, delete tempfile --> repeat.